# Динамический рендер Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Всем привет!
Я через шаблонизатор EJS отдаю на клиент HTML

Node.js :

```
const renderView = (uniq = [1,2,3,4,5]) => {
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.render("index", { uniq });
    });
}
```

EJS:

```
            <h1>Привет</h1>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text" name="" id="" />
                <button type="submit" name="" id="">начать</button>
            </form>
            <% if (uniq.length) { %>
                <h2><%=uniq.length%></h2>
             <% } %>
        </div>
```

И все хорошо, на клиенте я вижу инпут и длину массива uniq который указан в параметрах по умолчанию.

Но потом я хочу эту длину изменить и отрисовать на клиенте новое значение, с новыми данными, но когда я заново вызываю функцию renderView с новыми данными когда они обновляются после вычислений, то ничего не происходит, UI остается прежним.
Заранее спасибо! Или тут нужны сокеты?

Comment: Если за страницей пользвователь приходит 1 раз, то никак. Если вам надо динамически менять данные на клиенте по событиям сервера, то да, сокеты будут как раз кстати, только отправлять надо будет не страницу, а данные и по событию на клиенте их рендерить.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. Я просто в бэке вообще ноль)